# Load policy file from different ports

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have flash/air app, which works with network. So, I need to load policy file from my xmlsocket, but it could be placed on different ports.
Most important to load it with second port, when first is not reachable.
Now I try to use this code (formally):

```
try {
    Security.loadPolicyFile(xmlsocket://" + _url + ":" + 843);
} catch (error:Error) {
    try {
       Security.loadPolicyFile(xmlsocket://" + _url + ":" + 33333);
    } catch (error:Error) {
       trace("policy loading error");
    }       
} finally {
    if (_connection)
        _connection.open();
}
```

But I don't sure this block generates exception when destination port 843 locked or when no crossdomain.xml found on it, especially on different platforms (browser, AIR desktop app, AIR mobile app).
Could anyone clarify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadPolicyFile` won't throw any error. Flash has a built in sequence of tries to load such a policy file (cannot find it right now, but it was something like first load from the same location (http), then from master domain, then from different ports, etc.)

What this means is that it will internally try to load all the files that are marked for loading, before making the real request. So you can directly do this:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile(xmlsocket://" + _url + ":" + 843);
Security.loadPolicyFile(xmlsocket://" + _url + ":" + 33333);
```

And IF any of those request return a valid policy file - everything will work properly.